# how to set UITableView's scroll position to previous location when click "load earlier items" button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a tableView like iOS `iMessage` detail view. And also I've a button at the top of tableView which used by "load earlier messages".

When I scrolled tableView to top, my button appears and after I clicked the button, I fill earlier records and reload tableView.

While the records are repopulating in tableView, scrolls position does not change.

By the way, I tried to keep scroll previous position value and `setcontentoffset` to previous `CGPoint`. But I realized that the scrollposition always be 0 when I clicked button. So, after I setcontentoffset, scroll stays the top..

I need to relocate scrollview's position to previous area.

**--- Edit ---**

I try to improve my method which "keeping previous location of scrollview".

And I found the solution and works great. I'll share for all;

add this to .h file: `@property (nonatomic) CGFloat scrollsPreviousLocation;`
and `@synthesize scrollsPreviousLocation;` to .m file.

Now, Here is the trick: I calculate the position of scroll from bottom.. Not from Top.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    scrollsPreviousLocation = (self.tableView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

After the calculation process, Now I need to set content offset to previous location;

```
[tableView reloadData];
CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0,tableView.contentSize.height - scrollsPreviousLocation);
[tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
```

Comment: [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated: YES]; set the point where you want to scroll the tableview

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you are on top of your table view before loading previous content, you are at 0 for `contentOffset`. If you want to be able to stay at the same scroll position after reloading the table view with previous messages row above, you will have to do this :

```
// Save the contentSize of your table view before reloading it
CGFloat oldTableViewHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height;

// Reload your table view with your new messages

// Put your scroll position to where it was before
CGFloat newTableViewHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, newTableViewHeight - oldTableViewHeight);
```

That's it !

If your previous table view content size height was 10 and the new one was 19, you want to place your content offset to 9 (so 10 from the bottom like before the reloading) which is equal to `19 - 10`.

Comment: This is better and easier from my solution :) Thanks

Comment: Sweet, super simple. Although it doesn't work with `[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths...]` still very good.

Comment: It gives different position, if the rows are of variable height and if there are multiple sections in the tableview.
I was not able to find a good solution for that scenario, If anyone does please let me know too.

Answer (score 2):

the answer from @Kevin Hirsch work,but in auto layout mode ,remember to add tableView.layoutIfNeeded() ,or else you will get the estimate height.
here is my code in swift:

```
// Save the contentSize of your table view before reloading it

let oldTableViewHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height

// Reload your table view with your new messages

self.tableView.layoutIfNeed()

// Put your scroll position to where it was before

let newTableViewHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height;

self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, newTableViewHeight - oldTableViewHeight);
```