# UICollectionView load items on top - load more option

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I building message app with meteor-iOS, everything is going great but I'm trying to make a load more feature but I can't maintain/save the position of scroll view(When I scroll to top I want to load more items but keep the scroll view in the same position as before the insert)

My Code:

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {



    if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert {

        self.blockOperations.append(
            NSBlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                if let this = self {

                    this.collectionView!.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!])

                }
                })
        )
    }
    else if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update {
        self.blockOperations.append(
            NSBlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                if let this = self {


                    this.collectionView!.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!])
                }
                })
        )
    }
    else if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move {

        self.blockOperations.append(
            NSBlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                if let this = self {
                    this.collectionView!.moveItemAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
                }
                })
        )
    }
    else if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete {

        self.blockOperations.append(
            NSBlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                if let this = self {
                    this.collectionView!.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!])
                }
                })
        )
    }



}

 self.collectionView!.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
            for operation: NSBlockOperation in self.blockOperations {
                operation.start()
            }
            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                self.blockOperations.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)


        })
```

I'm using core data and meteor-ios. those anyone know what I can do? I also tried [how to set UITableView's scroll position to previous location when click "load earlier items" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820717/how-to-set-uitableviews-scroll-position-to-previous-location-when-click-load-e) any many other without success :(

Thank you very much!!

Comment: hi, did you solve?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I made if statement between range 20-50 to contentOffset.y. If it between those values so call loadMore() once.

Make bool value to save isLoadFinish and wait until the cell update. If you wouldn't do it the loadMore() will call multiple time.

For UX experience you have to save the old contentOffset.y before calling loadMore() and reset it after the load.

I will need to improve it a lot, simple hack for now.

Good luck.

Comment: give us some explainable code, i have try as you same but not working